# skip gram vector representation

Tags: neural-network, nlp, ai

I am using SVM for sentiment analysis project , I want to use n-skip gram for vector representation because I need to keep the semantic meaning between words ,
so I need to make vectors that belongs to a specified class be close to each other , how can I determine the most suitable n-skip to use? (means 2-skip or 3-skip or 4-skip ....),
I am using doc2Vec in python.